# Display content of metabox if filled in

Tags: customization

I was wondering if it is possible to put in the code that you want something to display if there is content in the metabox.

I have a metabox in the post type projects, In this metabox, the customer can fill in the website of the project, this is showing in a div.
If the customer doesn't fill in anything i want the div to dissapear.

It had to be something like isset i think.

What I had in mind

```
if (get_meta = true){
<div class="websitebutton"><?php meta('website-link-project'); ?></div>
}
else{
//nothing happens
}
```

But that's incorrect, just an idea of how i think it can be.
I searched alot around on the internet, but can't find the answer.

I created the meta boxes with the morefields plugin.

Does someone has an idea of how i can get this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the premise, that `website-link-project` is the key of the postmeta in question and you know the post's ID (or this being in The Loop, respectively):

```
<?php
    /* store post ID and metadata in variables */
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $website_link = get_post_meta( $postid, 'website-link-project', true );

    /* output some HTML on the condition of $website_link being meaningful */
    if ( ! empty( $website_link ) ) {
        echo '<div class="websitebutton">' . $website_link . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

The above *might* work as is, depending on whether my assumptions were correct.
Note that I don't know the plugin you are using at all.

[`get_the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) will only work within [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), if you're somewhere else, you'll have to grab the ID from elsewhere as well.

[`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) is WP's native function for retrieval of post metadata. Your plugin might provide additional ones.

As for the conditional in the above:
PHP's [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) pretty much does what its name tells you - it checks whether a variable is considered "empty" (`''` a string with no characters, `array()` empty array, `NULL`, `false`, `0` integer zero, and such). Since we want the condition to be evaluated to `true` if the variable is *not* empty, we negate the expression with a [`!`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).